# Type with fixed length > 64 in C

Tags: c, types

I'm currently writing some cryptographic code in C that has to deal with numbers greater than what uint64_t is able to hold. (It's for doing HDCP authentication, and one of the cipher values is 84 bits)

What would be the best way to do this? One of the variables I need to store is 84 bits long — should I take one uint64_t for the low 64 bits, and an uint32_t for the high 20 bits? This seems like a hack to me, but I'm not sure if there's really a better solution, especially for storing in a structure.

The ideal alternative would be declaring a custom datatype, like uint64_t, but instead 84 bits long, which behaves the same way. Is this even possible? I'm not sure if libc can handle variables with bit widths not multiples of 8, but an 88 bit type could work for that, although I'm not even sure how feasible declaring a custom bit-width data type is.

**Edit:** I've checked for uint128_t, but that doesn't seem to exist in clang's C99 mode. I'll be doing standard arithmetic and bit operations on this, the standard shebang associated with crypto code.

Comment: What sorts of operations are you doing on this value?

Comment: What are you going to use the int for? Arithmetic? C89? C99? gnu? Intel? AMD? All above?

Comment: @Xymostech: I'm expecting to do standard arithmetic and bit operations on the value. The code is just standard C99, and is going to be ported to ARM, for one.

Comment: Some recent versions of GCC (4.7.1, for example) support `__int128` and `unsigned __int128`.  However, it appears that `clang` (as in `Apple clang version 4.1 (tags/Apple/clang-421.11.65) (based on LLVM 3.1svn)`) does not support it.  You'd also need to verify that it is available on ARM.

Comment: You might find this useful; (in general): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture#Advanced_SIMD_.28NEON.29 and an interesting article on NEON crypto http://cr.yp.to/highspeed/neoncrypto-20120320.pdf It would probably also be useful to look at ffmpeg, openssl and the like to see how they do various tasks. Lot to learn there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

7 years ago my cryptography professor introduced us to [MIRACL](http://certivox.com/solutions/miracl-crypto-sdk/) open source library, which contained a very fast implementation of cryptographic functions and the facilities to work on big precision numbers. It's been a long time since I used it, but it seems to be still in good shape. Maybe it's not ideal if your problem is simply to represent exactly 84-bit values and nothing else, but it might be a more general solution.

Comment: Huh, that library seems nice, small and fast — will certainly come in handy for a bunch more projects than this!

Answer (score 3):

OK, I just installed a 32-bit Clang 3.1, and this works:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned __int128 i;
    printf("%d\n", sizeof(i));
}
```

(And prints "16".)

Comment: @TristanSeifert I installed Clang and updated the answer. Hopefully your version of Clang support this too.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, that is supported. I was just a bit thrown off by the fact that it wouldn't be uint128_t or something, but thanks for the answer. =P

Comment: @TristanSeifert Yeah, __int128 is compiler specific. But if you ever need to build using another compiler, you should hopefully be able to just `typedef` it to whatever that other compiler supports.

Comment: I'd hope that this isn't just something specific to the x86 architecture, though — I'll have to do some testing later if my ARM toolchain supports this.

Comment: the 128 types are usually only available on 64 bit architectures, the same way that 64 bit types are emulated on 32 bit architectures. (at least with gcc) (sorry for the late comment, I couldn't resist :)

Answer (score 2):

If you need more than 64 bits, and there is no integer type with more than 64 bits in the target environment, then you must use something else. You will have to use two variables, an array, or perhaps a struct with several members. You will also have to create the operations yourself, such as a plus function if you want to add numbers.

There is no built-in support in C to easily and automatically create N-bit integers.

Answer (score 1):

What about the [GNU Multiple Precision (GMP)](http://gmplib.org) library? It claims arbitrary precision:

> GMP is a free library for arbitrary precision arithmetic, operating on signed integers, rational numbers, and floating point numbers. There is no practical limit to the precision except the ones implied by the available memory in the machine GMP runs on. GMP has a rich set of functions, and the functions have a regular interface.